Trouble installing python3.11-venv on debian 12
I'm having some issues trying to get virtualenv working on debian 12, it's hard to decipher what exactly is the problem. I've run apt update and apt upgrade as well, it's a fresh network install of Debian from just a few days ago.
$ python3 -m venv code_execution_env
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt install python3.11-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

Failing command: /home/chris/projects/claude-engineer/code_execution_env/bin/python3

$ sudo apt install -y python3.11-venv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.11-venv : Depends: python3.11 (= 3.11.2-6+deb12u2) but 3.11.2-6+deb12u3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I've also tried instead python3-venv, python3.11-full package with no luck either:
$ sudo apt-get install python3.11-full
[sudo] password for chris: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.11-full : Depends: python3.11 (= 3.11.2-6+deb12u2) but 3.11.2-6+deb12u3 is to be installed
                   Depends: python3.11-venv (= 3.11.2-6+deb12u2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: python3.11-doc but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: python3.11-examples but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

apt-cache policy:
$ apt-cache policy python3.11 python3.11-venv
python3.11:
  Installed: 3.11.2-6+deb12u3
  Candidate: 3.11.2-6+deb12u3
  Version table:
 *** 3.11.2-6+deb12u3 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.11.2-6+deb12u2 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages
python3.11-venv:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.11.2-6+deb12u2
  Version table:
     3.11.2-6+deb12u2 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages

Tried apt --fix-broken install:
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded

Any pointers would be helpful, it's tricky to know if this is just some python packaging issue or perhaps I need to focus further on the exact error being python3.11-venv : Depends: python3.11 (= 3.11.2-6+deb12u2) but 3.11.2-6+deb12u3 is to be installed.
https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/python3.11 also states something concerning which is:

package is gone This package is not in any development repository.
This probably means that the package has been removed (or has been
renamed). Thus the information here is of little interest ... the
package is going to disappear unless someone takes it over and
reintroduces it.


Please add the output of apt-cache policy python3.11 python3.11-venv to your question. The candidate version of both packages should be 3.11.2-6+deb12u3, from the security archive. Try running apt-get update again, and check the candidate versions again.

For what it's worth, there are no issues installing python3.11-venv in the debian:12 Docker container: docker run --rm debian:12 sh -c 'apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3.11-venv'

@Kusalananda The security repository is missing, that's why the new update isn't shown in apt policy.

Based on the output of apt policy, the security repo is missing in your sources.list.
Edit your sources.list following this example on Debian wiki by adding this line:
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main 

Then run:
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt install -y python3.11-venv

Package: python3.11-venv (3.11.2-6+deb12u3) [security]

Wow thanks! It seems I had deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security instead.
